# VS 2017 RC, F5 doesn't work with project configured for target "framework" (net462): The "RunCommand" property is not defined

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.1

To configure asp.net-core project to use "framework" target (net462) it is required to delete package from csproj file:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="1.1.0" />
```

Because it is for "Core" platform only.

May be because of this Visual Studio F5 button (Run) stopped working:

[image]

Is it possible to "reintegrate" asp.core targeted to net462 with Visual Studio?

**ToolsVersion problem:**

One question aside, what we should know about ToolsVersion from `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" ToolsVersion="15.0">` ? Till that moment I thought that we should worry about `dotnet -v` (aka tooling version). How to know which sdk's "ToolsVersion" is the last  and which is actually installed on developer's computer?

**Reproducing**

I can't reproduce it with VS default ASP.CORE projects.
It is happens only with Spa Services projects.

Comment: try removing the tools version, not sure if that is needed there and it might be targeting the wrong version...

Comment: so instead of <Project Sdk="Microsoft.Sdk.Web" ToolsVersion="15.0"> you want just <Project Sdk="Microsoft.Sdk.Web">

Comment: `Microsoft.NETCore.App` is only for .NET Core. You have to remove it for full .NET Framework applications, it is only a meta package for portalble .NET Core apps anyways

Comment: @ThePaxBisonica Thank you, but no, this doesn't help. F5 still not working with the same error

Comment: @Tseng The something like it I know, but "met package for portable Core apps" sounds so mystic and myzzy that I can't eliminate that VS integration is done through it.

Comment: Meta package only means it is an empty package which references other common used packages for .NET Core, so you don't have to reference 20-30 packages manually. You can safely remove it when targeting .NET 4.x. You can see a list of packages it references here http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.App/

Comment: try changing it to a console app using   <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>

Comment: @ThePaxBisonica Thank you for your help! but changing output type to Exe (from winexe) also doesn't help (of course including dotnet restore/build)...

Comment: @ThePaxBisonica one question aside, what we should know about ToolsVersion from <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" ToolsVersion="15.0"> ? Till that moment I thought that we should worry about dotnet -v (tooling version only). How to know which sdk's "ToolsVersion" is the last  and which installed?

Comment: @ThePaxBisonica , after VS restart <OutputType>Exe</OutputType> stat working.

Comment: nice! where is my vote up :(

Comment: @ThePaxBisonica How I can give you a vote?

Comment: you should be able to do it on the comment

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij the name or location of the file would have been a help for people (like me) experiencing the same error.

Comment: @Stumble - it is all about *.proj file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As "The Pax Bisonica" suggested in comments:

Changing:

```
<OutputType>winexe</OutputType>
```

To:

```
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
```

helps, but only after Visual Studio restart (`dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` is not enough!!!). 
Together I have removed /bin and /obj folders so may be those steps also need to be included.

**About:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" ToolsVersion="15.0">
```

As I understand there ToolsVersion shares its value "15" from "Visual Studio 15" - prerelease/development name of Visual Studio 2017. I can't find an information about plans to change it with VS 2017 release. VS 2015's editions ToolsVersion = 14

Comment: This causes a console window to display though, right?

Comment: My problem was with ASP site project